# C++ nested loop issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ok, this is pretty bizarre...
I'm working on my final project for this class, and it has a series of loops that tell the program what to do based on user input. They worked just fine. I then coded another loop inside one of the loops, and all of a sudden the program isn't working -- meaning I just had it test something simple and it fails miserably. I checked, and I didn't code it differently than any of the other loops, so I don't think that is the problem. I also tried switching compilers, and that didn't change it either.

Here is the problem code with the loop structure:

```
vector<Item*> inventory;
string usrInptOptn = "default";
string usrInptOptn2 = "default";

while (true) {
    // Get user choice
    cout << "\nEnter (p)rint, (a)dd, (u)pdate, (r)emove, or (q)uit: ";
    getline(cin, usrInptOptn);

    // Process user choice
    if (usrInptOptn.size() == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'p') {
        PrintInventory(inventory);
    }
    else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'a') {
        cout << "\nEnter (b)ook or (p)roduce: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptOptn);

        if (usrInptOptn2.at(0) == 'b') {
            cout << "needs work..." << endl;            //Something fishy going on here...
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn2.at(0) == 'p') {
            cout << "something isn't working here" << endl;
            inventory = AddItemToInventory(inventory);
        }
    }
    else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'u') {
        inventory = UpdateItemQtyInInventory(inventory);
    }
    else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'r') {
        inventory = RemoveItemFromInventory(inventory);
    }
    else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'q') {
        cout << "\nGood bye." << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated for this! :D Thanks in advance!
-Danny

Comment: Where the code says "needs work..." or "something isn't working here" is where I tested it, and nothing is printing, which is mostly how I know it isn't working.

Comment: The line before, you're reading into usrInptOptn instead of usrInptOptn2

Comment: I don't see any nested loops.

Comment: cout << "\nEnter (b)ook or (p)roduce: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptOptn2); // May be you forgot usrInptOptn2 ??

Comment: @DBug , what do you suggest I change? Or rather, how should it be structured differently?

Comment: Where is the variable `usrInptOptn2` actually declared and set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
getline(cin, usrInptOptn);
```

instead of

```
getline(cin, usrInptOptn2);
```

As it stands the section that isnt working is checking the word "default"

Comment: That works now... Thanks! XD